# Converting h263 to h264 in iOS

Tags: iphone, ffmpeg, avfoundation, h.264

I am downloading a video with h263 codec and 3gp container on an iOS application. iOS cannot play h263 videos so the solution is to convert it to h264. Can I do that with AV Foundation? Or I have to use FFMPEG to do that?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do that with AVFoundation, you'll need to do it from other resource.

Comment: Can you tell me what resources can I use? Can I decode H263 video with FFMPEG and encode it with AV Foundation?

Comment: FFMPEG For example, as you said

Comment: You would honestly be better off setting up a server and creating a ffmpeg based conversion on the server side. You will not be able to get good performance on the mobile device, so it is better not to even try.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org) to play h263.

Here you have [FFmpeg4iOS](https://github.com/ciphor/ffmpeg4ios)